# Show the dimension of $F[x]/(p(x))$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p(x) = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in F[x]$ be a non-constant polynomial of degree $n$ and let $V=\frac{F[x]}{(p(x))}$. Why the dimension of $V$ is n?

P.S. I thought it is $n+1$ because I think $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^{n-1},x^n\}$ is the generator of $V$ but apparently it is incorrect. Can anyone explain why it is regarding the basis of $V$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have one too many powers of $x$ in your proposed basis, namely the highest power: $x^{n}$. The reason is that the quotient is rigged precisely such that the class of $x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0} = 0$ in $V$, and so $x^{n} = -a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-\cdots-a_{1}x-a_{0}$ as classes in $V$. This shows that $x^{n}$ is a linear combination of $1, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ in $V$. I think the best way to show that $1, x, \ldots, x^{n-1}$ form a basis of $V$ is to use Euclidean division by $p(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congruence classes mod $p(X)$ have canonical representatives in $F[X]$:

Any polynomial $f(X)$ can be divided by $p(X)$ with Euclidean division:
$$f(X)=q(X)p(X)+r(X)\qquad(\deg r<n)$$
Hence the representatives of the congruence classes are polynomials in $F[X]$ with degree $\le n-1$. A basis of this subvector space of polynomials is the set $\;\{1,X, X^2,\dots,X^{n-1}\}$.

Comment: I see, it is very clear, thanks.